# How to shorten a series of For loop blocks into one

Tags: vba, excel

I have a series of code blocks containing For Loops here, and I'd like to scale down this code so that it can work the same way but be about as long as one of these blocks of code rather than having it be 12 blocks in length. As you can see, each block is a group of 6, the challenge I'm having here is shortening the code while keeping my variables in groups of 6. In this program, values are generated in two columns and go in sequential order.
For example:

When m is 1 to 6, the value p needs to be 1 for all six values

When m is 7 to 12, the value p needs to be 2 for all six values

When m is 13 to 18, the value p needs to be 3 for all six values

etc....

```
For m = 1 To 6 'Riser
        For p = 1 To 1 'Car
            If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then
                ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p
                Exit For
            End If
        Next p
    Next m

For m = 7 To 12 'Riser
    For p = 2 To 2 'Car
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then
            ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p
            Exit For
        End If
    Next p
Next m

For m = 13 To 18 'Riser
    For p = 3 To 3 'Car
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then
            ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p
            Exit For
        End If
    Next p
Next m

For m = 19 To 24 'Riser
    For p = 4 To 4 'Car
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then
            ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p
            Exit For
        End If
    Next p
Next m

For m = 25 To 30 'Riser
    For p = 5 To 5 'Car
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then
            ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p
            Exit For
        End If
    Next p
Next m

For m = 31 To 36 'Riser
    For p = 6 To 6 'Car
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then
            ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p
            Exit For
        End If
    Next p
Next m

For m = 37 To 42 'Riser
    For p = 7 To 7 'Car
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then
            ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p
            Exit For
        End If
    Next p
Next m

For m = 43 To 48 'Riser
    For p = 8 To 8 'Car
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then
            ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p
            Exit For
        End If
    Next p
Next m

For m = 49 To 54 'Riser
    For p = 9 To 9 'Car
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then
            ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p
            Exit For
        End If
    Next p
Next m

For m = 55 To 60 'Riser
    For p = 10 To 10 'Car
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then
            ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p
            Exit For
        End If
    Next p
Next m

For m = 61 To 66 'Riser
    For p = 11 To 11 'Car
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then
            ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p
            Exit For
        End If
    Next p
Next m

For m = 67 To 72 'Riser
    For p = 12 To 12 'Car
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then
            ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p
            Exit For
        End If
    Next p
Next m
```

Is there a way to increment these values m and p so that they will go up to 78 while maintaining these groups of six for each block?

Comment: your inner loop is  unnecessary as it only goes from one index to the same index each time.  It can be removed as per @marucciboy2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hereby a simple solution:

```
For m = 1 To 72'Riser
    If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & ((m - 1) \ 6) + 1)) Then
        ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = ((m - 1) \ 6) + 1
    End If
Next m
```

Comment: Dangit, yup this is the simple solution that I was having trouble coming up with

Comment: To simplify it a bit further: instead of Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(m / 6, 0) use (m-1)\6

Comment: @EvR, we need whole numbers :)

Comment: @JvdV Yep, that's why \ instead of /  ;-)

Comment: @Evr, Overlooked :(. Perfect! But your edition starts at 0, I've edited it a little :)

Comment: this wouldn't follow OP'a code logic which, for each _not empty_  _car_ would exit as soon as meeting the corresponding _risers_ first _not empty_ value

Answer (score 7):

There might be a more clever way to do this, but I would use the modulo function. The modulo returns the remainder when you divide two numbers, so if you divide `m` by 6, the remainder will only be 0 if `m` is a multiple of 6. When that is the case, you just increment the variable I added called `everySix`

```
Dim everySix As Long
everySix = 1

Dim wasFound As Boolean

For m = 1 To 78
    If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & everySix)) Then

        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not wasFound Then
            ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value2 = everySix
            wasFound = True
        End If

        If m Mod 6 = 0 Then
            everySix = everySix + 1
            wasFound = False
        End If

    End If
Next m
```

Comment: Nice solution. I was thinking about `Mod` but wanted to get the alternative `Select Case` solution out there first. (I'd prefer modulo, if it produces the correct results - it seems so much smoother.) :)

Comment: this wouldn't follow OP's code logic which, for each not empty car would exit as soon as meeting the corresponding risers first not empty value. Moreover `Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & everySix))` check is being repeated with no use: you'd better move it as an outer check before looping through corresponding risers loop.

Answer (score 3):

following the logic of OP's code, I'd go as follows:

```
For p = 1 To 12 ' loop through cars
    If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then ' proceed only if current car isn't empty
        For m = (p - 1) * 6 + 1 To p * 6 'Riser ' loop through current car corresponding risers range
            If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) Then ' if current riser isn't empty
                ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p ' mark with current car
                Exit For ' exit loop and process next car
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Your inner `for` loops are not necessary. You can simply replace `for p = 1 to 1` with `p = 1` and remove the corresponding `Next p`.

That said, I think the following structure could reduce code duplication a bit:

```
For m = 1 To 72 'Riser
    Select Case m
    Case 1 to 6
        p = 1
    Case 7 to 12
        p = 2
    ' and so on...
    End Select

    If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then
        ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p
        'Exit For ' You might need to replace this line with something adequate if necessary
    End If
Next m
```

Now the `Select Case` statement will take care of appropriately assigning values to `p` and you can do all the work in one loop. This solution would be preferable if that rule *increase p for every six m* isn't set in stone. (Easier to change assignments that way.)

Now if you say the *increase p for every six m* rule **is** set in stone, then I'd recommend you use [@Marcucciboy2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51822945/7778672) instead.

---

Generally I'd suggest to move the logic to assign a value to `p` depending on `m` out into its own function.

```
Public Sub YourSubStartsHere()
' [...]
For m = 1 To 72 'Riser
    p = GetPFromM(m)
    If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Riser" & m)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p)) Then
        ws.Range("C1").Offset(m).Value = p
        'Exit For ' You might need to replace this line with something adequate if necessary
    End If
Next m
End Sub

Private Function GetPFromM(ByVal m as Long) as Long
    ' Your preferred logic to get the new p here
    ' be it Select Case
    Select Case m
    Case 1 to 6
        GetPFromM = 1
    End Select
    ' or rounding up
    GetPFromM = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(m / 6, 0)
End Function
```

This way it would be rather easy to quickly plug in a new rule for p, if necessary.

Comment: I think this approach is also a bit easier to read, especially if someone is new to VBA.

Comment: `Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("Car_" & p))` check is being repeated with no use: you'd better move it as an outer check before looping through corresponding _risers_ loop.

Comment: @DisplayName I agree. But getting rid of it inside the loop requires some additional logic that I did not want to introduce at this point. I think it's well placed in an answer of its own (namely yours). :)